# Android: Making a record button in the notifications bar

Tags: android, static, nullpointerexception, android-activity, notifications

Hey guys I'm writing an app which has a custom xml notification with a button in it which does voice recording. I'm very close to done using a Broadcast Listener. The last feature I would like to do is to simply change the button text color to red while recording which is proving to be difficult.

I start here in createNotification()

```
    Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(this, playButtonListener.class);
    PendingIntent pbuttonIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, buttonIntent,0);
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pbuttonIntent);
```

ANd the playButtonListener() class looks like

```
    public static class playButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if(recording){
            setNotRecording(VoiceRecorder.activity); //VoiceRecorder is the 
            //activity and activity = this in onCreate()
            recorder.stop(); // stop recording
            recorder.reset(); // reset the MediaRecorder
            recording = false; // we are no longer recording
        }else{
            setRecording(VoiceRecorder.activity);

            if (recorder == null)
                recorder = new MediaRecorder(); // create MediaRecorder
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
            recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
```

And finally where I set the button in setRecording()

```
    public static void setRecording(Activity activity){
//Had to be static to use with playButtonListener
//Had to use activity because static doesnt work with findViewById

    Button b = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.red));//Crashes here where button 1 is the id on the 
//button on the notification
//The error is a null pointer so I guess the id isnt found?

    Button b2 = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.recordButton);//These buttons which are in the activity 
//opposed to outside the activity and work fine when I take out the first button
    b2.setText(R.string.stp);
    b2.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
            R.color.red));
    Button b3 = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.viewSaved);
    b3.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Any ideas on why I can't change the text color of the button? I've tried somethings like making a global static public button = button1 but that button still crashes at the same spot

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.red));//Crashes here where button 1 is the id on the 
//button on the notification
//The error is a null pointer so I guess the id isnt found?
```

You're right-- the button is not found. This is because `findViewById` will look through the xml file that you specify in `setContentView`

You need to use `findViewById` on an instance of the view that contains the button:

```
Button btn = contentView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Comment: Well the idea is that the text white while it's not recording and red when it is.